# Disconnected loop Feynman diagrams

Tags: feynman

I'm trying to obtain the disconnected loop diagrams in the pictures in latex, it could be  fine with any Feynman diagrams package. Could you give me some suggestions? [image: diagram 1]

[[image: diagram 2][2]]
[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Use Tikz, which at least the newer Feynman packages use anyway. Start reading the tutorials in the pgfmanual several times. We look forward to see your code-trials.